# Creating a program using OpenCV for a wide variety of cameras using GENICAM API and C++

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, camera, gige-sdk

Hi Everyone I am trying to make a camera come up and live stream images using openCV and the GenICam API for the drivers rather than one from the manufacturer.  Does anyone know the proper way to use the GenICam API in C++ to pull up the camera as well as implement some basic features like gain?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question seems very vague... you want a camera (which camera?) to *"come up"* (from where?) using OpenCV and GenICam API (which?) drivers *"rather than the one from the manufacturer"* (huh? isn't GenICam the manufacturer? if not which cameras do you mean?). Then you want to *"live stream"* (what? to where? how?) and *"pull something up from somewhere"*?

Comment: I am sorry, allow me to elaborate, I am using a Basler camera and rather than using the downloadable SDK from them I am trying to make a program that can use any GenICam camera rather than just Basler cameras. This program should be able to open a window and grab video off of the camera, but I do not know how to properly implement the GenICam API to have my program and openCV code communicate with the camera.  I am also using Visual Studio 2012 as my compiler.

Comment: What camera? I'd avoid using OpenCV `VideoCapture` for any kind of production code.

Comment: Why is it best to avoid Video Capture? @DanMašek

Comment: Several of the backends for industrial cameras are quite limited in the extent you can control the cameras, and only work in polling mode. Check [the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules/videoio/src) to see for yourself. You also need to build OpenCV yourself and enable the specific drivers (and have the appropriate third party libraries).

Comment: So to be clear with Opencv I would need a library for each brand of camera, could I implement the Genicam API to get around that?  Also what is polling mode?

Comment: @DanMašek I forgot to reference you in my last comment

Answer (score 2):

[camera interface C API](https://github.com/motmot/libcamiface)

and

[A vision library for genicam based cameras](https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis)

Comment: Thank You @Programmer_ARM, can you tell me a little bit more on how to use these libraries?

Comment: Have a look at some examples with Aravis here (c++ and python) https://github.com/eudoxos/vrmagic-aravis .